# Reg exp search in notes/comments/description data in PostgreSQL 10.7

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have a scenario which I am not able to do in 10.7 version. Basically, I have a data column in which I need to find the Reg Exp pattern inside the data which is in the form of notes/comments/description.

For example, Data in the column : `The SSN number is 760-56-6289`

In the above data `760-56-6289` is the actual SSN number which I need to find across all schemas/tables/columns for the defined reg exp pattern. And, we can have a pre or post text for actual SSN value.

Could you please let me know how to achieve this PostgreSQL 10.7?

Please let me know if you need more information for the same.

Answer (score 0):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a13ccd710d823e687ffcc53ed43ade12)

```
SELECT
    (regexp_matches(mycolumn, '^.*([\d]{3}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{4}).*$'))[1]
FROM mytable
```

The RegEx means:

1. Start of text: `^`
2. arbitrary number of characters: `.*`
3. group of your number: `(...)`

   1. 3 digit characters: `[\d]{3}`
   2. `-` character
   3. 2 digits: `[\d]{2}`
   4. `-` character
   5. 4 digits: `[\d]{4}`
4. arbitrary number of characters: `.*`
5. end of text: `$`

`regexp_matches()` gives out all found groups as an array. So, there is only one group, the array contains only one value. This is your number which can be get with the index `[1]`

Comment: Why the anchor at the start and end?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe You're right. In that case they are not even necessary. Just wanted to give a more general solution if the examples were simplified. For that case the digit group is enough: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=6c84401d6ba6350ad53af5f11615b367

Comment: @S-Man Thanks...For the Reg Exp search, I have a function which uses the Dynamic sql  EXECUTE format('SELECT ctid FROM %I.%I WHERE cast(%I as text) ~*%L'
If I am adding .* for arbitrary no of chars

select * from search_keyword_new('^.*([ ]?((?!000|666|9\d{2})\d{3})([- ]?)((?!00)\d{2})([- ]?)((?!0000)\d{4})[ ]?).*$',schema,table);

But the to the function using .* producing many false positive cases as well.

Could we restrict these many false positive cases ?

Comment: Can you please show us a fiddle which reproduces the problem?